# passing real data into Material-UI Data Grid Rows

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, material-ui

I'm currently using the ASP .NET Core with React to build a web-based portal and would like to create a table using Material-UI Data Grid. Below is the example of Data Grid implementation where rows are assigned with hard-coded data. My question is that if it's possible to pass real data from sql database through controller into rows.

```html
<DataGrid
  columns={[{ field: 'name' }]}
  rows={[
    { id: 1, name: 'React' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Material-UI' },
  ]}
/>
```

This is the Account component to generate a table which is made by standard table from React. Here I successfully retrieve the real data through accountsController and it can be reached through this.State.accounts.

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Account extends Component {
    static displayName = Account.name;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { accounts: [], loading: true };
       
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.accountData();
    }

    static renderAccountsTable(accounts) {
        return (
            <table className='table table-striped' aria-labelledby="tabelLabel">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>AccountsID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {accounts.map(account =>
                        <tr key={account.accountsId}>
                            <td>{account.accountsId}</td>
                            <td>{account.name}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );        
    }

    render() {
        let contents = this.state.loading
            ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
            : Account.renderAccountsTable(this.state.accounts);

        return (
            <div>
                <h1 id="tabelLabel" >Account info</h1>
                <p>This component demostrates fetching data from sql server</p>
                {contents}
            </div>
            );
    }

    async accountData() {
        const response = await fetch('Accounts');
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ accounts: data, loading: false });
    }
}
```

Then I tried to pass data to rows. Below the controller class. Here I select only two columns in the table using anonymous type.

```html
                    public IEnumerable<Accounts> Index()
    {
        var accounts = _context.Accounts.Select(x => new { x.AccountsId, x.Name });
        return (IEnumerable<Accounts>)accounts;
    }
```

Then I tried to replace the renderAccountsTable with the following code .

```html
static renderAccountsTable(accounts) {
  const columns = [
            { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 90 },
            {
                field: 'name',
                headerName: 'Name',
                width: 150,
                editable: false,
            }];
  const rows = accounts;
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
                    <DataGrid
                        rows={rows}
                        columns={columns}
                        pageSize={5}
                        checkboxSelection
                        disableSelectionOnClick
                   />
                </div>
  );
 }
```

It does not work. The browser shows a blank page. It seems that the data types don't match each other. Any idea how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Extra info: below the Accounts class

```html
public partial class Accounts
    {
        public Guid AccountsId { get; set; }
        
        public string Name { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

And After seconds, the error message does appear in the browser:

Unhandled Rejection (Error): Material-UI: The data grid component requires all rows to have a unique id property.
A row was provided without id in the rows prop:

I made a change. I changed `const rows = accounts;` to `const rows = accounts.map((obj, index) => ({ AccountsId: index, Name: obj.Name }));`. And added `getRowId={(r) => r.AccountsId}` inside `DataGrid`.
The error disappears but the table does not show the Name data. See screenshot.[image] And actually I want AccountsId columns could be filled out with real data instead of index count (from 0 to length)

Comment: can you share what the console says?

Comment: I can't see `Accounts` class but have you checked that coulmn's field name are the same name of the property you want to show? Shouldn't be `AccountsId` and `Name`? Because on columns definition you wrote `id` and `name`

Comment: I added the error message and the Account class. Any further idea?

Comment: Error is quite clear: DataGrid wants that all row elements have a property calle id and this id must be unique.

Comment: ok. It works. Just change obj.Name to obj.name. But still how can I keep the real value of AccountsId instead of the default index count (from 0 to length)